# How to replace a value in an array's element with another element from the same array?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an element in an array, called $row[0], that contains this absolute pathname:

```
/home/<username>/puppet/config/files/$HOSTGROUP/$TOOLNAME/$VERSION
```

I'd like to replace each of the three variables listed in that path with three matching elements that are part of the same array...

```
$row[3]      (represents $HOSTGROUP)
$row[4]      (represents $TOOLNAME)
$row[5]      (represents $VERSION)
```

How can I do this in a Perl script?

Comment: Anything that you tried, and why it doesn't work?

Comment: The fact that the values are in an array is meaningless

Answer (score 2):

```
my %repl = (
   HOSTGROUP => $row[3],
   TOOLNAME  => $row[4],
   VERSION   => $row[5],
);

my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %repl;
my $re = qr/\$($pat)\b/;

$row[0] =~ s/$re/$repl{$1}/g;
```

or

```
my %repl = (
   HOSTGROUP => $row[3],
   TOOLNAME  => $row[4],
   VERSION   => $row[5],
);

$row[0] =~ s{(\$(\w+))}{
   if (exists($repl{$2})) {
      $repl{$2}
   } else {
      warn("Unrecognized var $2\n");
      $1
   }
}eg;
```